# console says next is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

am working on a project, and am triyng to verify my jwt token using a middleware, but am getting an error message in the console, it says "next is not defined",
here is my code

in login.js

```
const verifyy = require('./verifyJWT')

module.exports = (req, res)=> {
    verifyy(req, res, next)
}
```

and in verifyJWT.js which is where the middleware is, here is the code

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const fs = require('fs');

var public = fs.readFileSync('./public.pem');

module.exports = (req, res, next)=> {
    var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' });
    jwt.verify(token, public, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
        next();

    });
}
```

pls how can i solve this problem or what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in login.js, you are exporting an arrow function that not receive a next parameter in the arrow function, and you are passing a next to verifyy, so that next is undefined.

```
const verifyy = require('./verifyJWT')

module.exports = (req, res)=> {
    verifyy(req, res, next)
}
```

You can try passing the next in the login.

```
const verifyy = require('./verifyJWT')

module.exports = (req, res, next)=> {
    verifyy(req, res, next)
}
```

Comment: i tried it but now its not running the verifyy function

Comment: if it is the same one, can you provide the pice of code where you call the login module?.